# Shifting nested tikz scopes with a command

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to automate some things with tikz, and I am running into a problem that I do not understand.  Nesting scopes with shifts defined as commands does not work as I was expecting.

For example, this works perfectly :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\coord{(1,0)}
\begin{scope}[shift={\coord}]
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={\coord}]
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and it works correctly, as one can see by adding some `\node[fill,circle] at (0,0) {};` inside and outside the scopes

but the following fails :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\coord{(1,0)}
\begin{scope}[shift={\coord}]
  \begin{scope}[shift={\coord}]
  \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, this

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\coord{(1,0)}
\begin{scope}[shift={(1,0)}]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(1,0)}]
  \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

indeed works. I do not understand what is happening. `pdflatex` returns

```
Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.
See the tikz package documentation for explanation. ...
```

in the problematic case. The question is why does this happen ? I probably did something wrong, but I really do not see what.

Notice that adding length units does not fix the problem. However, a similar problem with `xshift` and `yshift` does not seem to happen. Also notice that I tried to simplify the code as much as possible ; that's why it draws nothing.

Thanks,

Comment: TikZ needs to expand `\coord` on its own. The algorithm that is used to parse a coordinate does this if it encounters something that is did not expect (here it does expect a `(` but doesn’t find it). Each expansion counts down a counter, if this counter reaches zero, TikZ gives up and presents you this error message. On a path, this counter is usually initialized with `100`. This is not the case on a `scope`. You can observe the same behavior if you use `shift=\ccoord` with `\def\ccoord{\coord}`. — **Best is to give TikZ the coordinate already expanded and do `shift/.expanded=coord`.**

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel well I cannot accept your comment as an answer, but it was exactly what I needed (the solution as well as the explanation). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As qrrbrbirlbel noted TikZ works with parsing letter-by-letter the command stream. It is a blessing and sometimes a curse depending on the context and when key value system is mixed with macros and literal text. So you can give a hand to TikZ to understand what it should read. So changing your definition without the parentheses is enough for it to go, *oh, that must be a coordinate then*

Also notice that braces are needed to hide the commas and brackets in the options and you can remove them here, so this doesn't cost you extra typing.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (0,-1) grid[step=1cm] (4,1);
\def\coord{1,0}
\begin{scope}[shift=(\coord)]
  \begin{scope}[shift=(\coord)]
      \begin{scope}[shift=(\coord)]
        \begin{scope}[shift=(\coord)]
        \node (a) at (0,0) {a};
        \end{scope}
      \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]